# Ошибка записи в excel файл

Tags: python, excel

Есть список строк по которому прохожу циклом и пытаюсь внести эти строки в `excel` файл с помощью библиотеки `xlwt`, но получаю ошибку `Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname='Python Sheet 1' rowx=0 colx=0` якобы я пытаюсь перезаписать ячейку. Что я делаю неправильно, если каждую итерацию увеличиваю номер столбца?

```py
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Python Sheet 1")
any_list = [values]
row, cell = 0, 0
for k in any_list:
   sheet1.write(row, cell, k)
   book.save('results.xls')
   cell += 1
```

Comment: Если вы уберете цикл и просто один раз попробуете `sheet1.write(row, cell, 777)` ошибка будет та же?

Comment: @Kromster дело в том, что несколько значений успешно записываются

Comment: Спросил, потому что вам жалуется явно на первый же элемент `0,0`

Comment: Странно, но мне всегда казалось нумерация колонок и строк в экселе начинается с 1, а не с нуля :) попробуйте, возможно ваш вариант.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в данном случае с 0

Comment: Вполне вероятно что у вас это так :) это просто предположение, та библиотека которой я пользуюсь вообще имеет буквенно-цифровые ключи(а1,б1....) :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а что за библиотека, подскажите

Comment: Вообще этот код нормально работает в Google Colab для записи вплоть до 255 значений, дальше оно ругается, что слишком большой номер столбца. Что-то вы недоговариваете.  Тут единственная проблема - что вы сохраняете книгу внутри цикла на каждой итерации, это не рационально, лучше после цикла это делать. У меня есть подозрение, что реально у вас в коде не те табуляции, которые вы проставили в вопросе. Может `cell += 1` у вас не попало внутрь цикла на самом деле?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin вас она врядли спасет, она для php и устарела лет на 10 наверное, https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код прекрасно работает в Google Colab. Единственный вариант при котором возможна данная ошибка, это если вы указали в вопросе не те табуляции, которые есть в коде и на самом деле у вас форматирование кода такое:

```py
row, cell = 0, 0
for k in any_list:
   sheet1.write(row, cell, k)
book.save('results.xls')
cell += 1
```

Я бы не удивился, потому что непонятно, зачем делать `book.save` каждую итерацию цикла, логично было бы вынести на после цикла. Ну а заодно случайно вынесли и инкремент столбца. В этом случае просто занесите инкремент обратно в цикл:

```py
row, cell = 0, 0
for k in any_list:
   sheet1.write(row, cell, k)
   cell += 1
book.save('results.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

По совету с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679641/77764):

> The problem is that overwriting of worksheet data is disabled by default in xlwt. You have to allow it explicitly, like so:

По умолчанию перезапись данных запрещена. Можно её включить:

```
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Python Sheet 1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

Comment: Так мне не надо перезаписывать, мне каждый раз нужно в новую ячейку записывать данные. И мне непонятно откуда ошибка, если я увеличиваю номер столбца

Comment: Возможно, у вас ячейка 0,0 проинициализирована каким-то значением, типа пустой строки. Попробуйте, проверьте.